# Run a system command interactively in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, openssl, telnet

I want to run the OPENSSL from MATLAB and store the command output in my workspace. My attempt is as follows:

1. I installed Win32OPENSLL_Light.
2. I typed the command 
   [a, b] = system('openssl s_client -connect my.address.to');

However, when I do this, both variables a and b has nothing in them. It is probably because openssl command opens up and waits for the commands to be sent to the server. How can I get the output corresponding to individual command that I send to my.address.to when the connection is once established.

If I am not wrong, the same problem exists if I telnet to a remote address. I want the output corresponding to each command stored in a separate variable. However, the system command in MATLAB doesn't return anything for as long as the connection is open.

Comment: try `system('openssl s_client -connect my.address.to','-echo')`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov your method gives the output when the complete command is executed and I close the ssl connection. The entire session is logged into the variable 'b'. However, I want to store the output corresponding to individual commands during the session.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)